# Divide the 5th column by 3 in all the files in the directory?

Tags: linux, bash, csv, awk, find

How can I loop through all files in the directory and divide the 5th column values by 3? I'd like for the changes to be made to the files themselves and the first row should be skipped, as it is a field header. The fields are separated by commas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it (if you have all files in under one directory, if not then use find):

```
for f in /path/to/dir/* ; do 
    awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}NR>1{$5=$5/3}1' "$f" > "$f".tmp && mv "$f".tmp "$f"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

This script will do the trick:

```
#!/bin/bash

script=$(basename $0)

find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | while IFS= read -r file
do
    if [[ $(basename "$file") !=  "$script" ]]; then
        awk 'NR>1{$5=$5/3}1' FS=, OFS=, "$file" > tmp
        mv tmp "$file"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

perl is handy for in-place edits:

```
for f in *; do 
    perl -F, -i -lane 'BEGIN {$,=","} $F[4]/=3 if $.>1; print @F' "$f"
done
```

Comment: How can I modify this to truncate the decimal values?

Comment: Change `$F[4]/=3` to `$F[4] = int($F[4]/3)`